# No Unity bar, no window bar on Saucy and Trusty

Tags: 13.10, 14.04, titlebar

After I upgraded from `Raring`, I started not seeing bars of `Unity` and also on all windows. Some phenomenon:

- `CTRL` + `ALT` + `T` not opening terminal
- Happens only with my main user account

  - ie. When logging in with `Guest` account things look normal.
  - Log in display also looks normal.
- Wallpapers on bacgground are displayed.

Only possible way to operate on terminal is from `ssh -X`, but:

```
(logged into 192.168.1.15)
$ export DISPLAY=192.168.1.15:0.0
$ unity &
[2] 5155
nwind@wind-t440s:~$ stop: Unknown job: unity-panel-service
start: Unknown job: unity-panel-service
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display 192.168.1.15:0.0
compiz (core) - Info: Stopping plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: core
$ w
 19:32:39 up  1:02,  2 users,  load average: 2.00, 2.01, 2.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
nwind    :0       :0               18:32   ?xdm?   3:56   0.13s init --user
nwind    pts/1    wind-serval.loca 18:52    7.00s  0.21s  0.00s w
```

I was at a loss and upgraded to `Trusty` (that was original purpose anyway) but things remain the same. What's wrong? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: At a loss, I just re-created a user account with the same name and it works fine. Hope this is simpler than re-installing the entire OS.