# Blank screen after updating to 14.04

Tags: login, 14.04

Since I upgraded to 14.04, I cannot login to Ubuntu "normally" anymore. A blank screen with the mouse cursor is shown, nothing else.

I can login only if I choose the safety terminal mode, in the login screen. In this case, the graphical mode starts, but only displays a xterm, which I can use to launch other programs, like google chrome.

Tried the steps in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver), but nothing worked.

Appreciate any help. Please let me know if (and how) I should provide more details to help solving this issue.

Thank a lot,

Ricardo

Comment: Is [the phenomenon in this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457595/no-unity-bar-no-window-bar-on-saucy-and-trusty) similar?

Comment: Indeed it's very similar. The issue seems to be in Unity, I can manually launch it via tty. Unfortunately, there is no solution in that post...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar behaviour.

Only thing that helped for me was reinstalling 14.04 with the option of keeping all the installed applications. Took several hours but the malady was gone.

The thing I did not try and that might help, however, is deleting the .Xauthority file from Your home directory as described here somewhere: 
[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I have had similar issue with an earlier Ubuntu and then it resolved like that.

Comment: Tried deleting .Xauthority, but it didn't work... Also thinking about reinstalling, I've already lost several days trying to solve this.